# Array formula for large dataset

Tags: google-sheets

Right now I am using one formula per cell over 5000 cells. Here is the formula:

```
    =ifna(query(sheet1!$A$2:$S, "Select s,p Where p <>'' AND B="&""""&n2&""""&"Limit 1"),ifna(query(sheet1!$a$2:$s, "Select s,p where P<>'' and B="&""""&o2&""""&"Limit 1"),""))
```

This formula does the following:

- ifna N2 in current sheet matches Column B in Sheet1 Display the value of Columns S & P in sheet1 where it is not blank and only show the first value you find.
- Else
  ifna O2 in current sheet matches Column B in Sheet1 Display the value of Columns S & P in sheet1 where it is not blank and only show the first value you find.

This formula works great. However. I run this for each row. So it is basically 5000 formulas running to get these matches.

How can I make one single formula that takes the value of each row in current sheet and matches it to one of the 5000 rows in SHEET1, and where there is a match take the value from two other columns and place them in the corresponding row in the current sheet.

I have tried a variety of combinations of arrayformulas, queries, and vlookups without success.

Example Data sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SMKU85a7vfA3bIMQiG9fJQbgOnT56FuFWl-tPes8uts/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you share a sample sheet? You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SMKU85a7vfA3bIMQiG9fJQbgOnT56FuFWl-tPes8uts/edit?usp=sharing

Here is an example sheet.. I changed the data and numbers to dummy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can try

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFNA(
    VLOOKUP(A2:A,{SHEET1!B:B,SHEET1!S:S,SHEET1!P:P},{2,3},0),
    IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B,{SHEET1!B:B,SHEET1!S:S,SHEET1!P:P},{2,3},0))))
```